# Using Union to return single row from 2 tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, union

I want to combine 2 tables into 1
and return it into 1 row per unique id

```
SELECT  
     try_convert(nvarchar(3),  StockRec.CustNo)  AS [CustNo]
    ,try_convert(nvarchar(3),  StockRec.LocationNo) AS [LocationNo]
    ,try_convert(nvarchar(8),  StockRec.ItemNo)      AS [ItemNo]
    ,try_convert(nvarchar(20), StockRec.Location)       AS [Location]
    ,try_convert(nvarchar(20), StockRec.Container)   AS [Container]
     FROM
(       SELECT  
                  CustNo
                , LocationNo
                , ItemNo
                , Location
                , Container
        FROM CustPurchases
UNION ALL
        SELECT
                  CustNo
                , LocationNo
                , ItemNo
                , Location
                , Container
        FROM CustomerSales
)StockRec
```

CustPurchases looks like

[image: CustPurchases]

and CustomerSales looks like

[image: CustomerSales]

However when I run the query i get 10 rows back instead of 5

Comment: Agree with Gordon's answer. In case there is confusion about UNION vs JOIN, think of it like this: a union will bridge together results, or "stack" them. A join will enmesh the results (generally speaking; depending on query) and retrieve a "combined" result set in a sense.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want five rows, I think you want `join`:

```
select . . .   -- the columns you want
from CustPurchases cp join
     CustSales cs
     on cs.custno = cp.custno;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using aggregation with group by

```
SELECT  
    CustNo
    ,LocationNo
    ,ItemNo
    ,max(Location)
    ,max(Container)
     FROM
(       SELECT  
                  CustNo
                , LocationNo
                , ItemNo
                , Location
                , Container
        FROM CustPurchases
UNION ALL
        SELECT
                  CustNo
                , LocationNo
                , ItemNo
                , Location
                , Container
        FROM CustomerSales
)StockRec group by CustNo
    ,LocationNo
    ,ItemNo
```

Comment: if I have an extra columns? price paid in CustPurchases this will be null in custSales, another column would be purchase price in CustSales this will be null in CustPurchases, 
and in top select we would calculate Purchase Price - Price Paid.
Would sum(Purchase Price - Price Paid) give me the correct result ?